# Fast numpy covariance for arrays of different shape

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, covariance

I need to obtain the covariance between an array `a` of shape `(M1, M2, N)` and another array `b` of shape `(N,)`.

What I currently do is use a `for` block:

```
import numpy as np

M1, M2, N = 23, 50, 117
a = np.random.uniform(-2., 2., (M1, M2, N))
b = np.random.uniform(-1., 1., N)

c = []
for i in range(M1):
    for j in range(M2):
        c.append(np.cov(a[i][j], b)[0, 1])
```

but it gets a bit slow for large `(M1, M2)`. Is there a way to speed this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always calculate the cov by hand. Here are two suggestions using `dot` and `einsum` respectively.

```
import numpy as np

M1, M2, N = 23, 50, 117
a = np.random.uniform(-2., 2., (M1, M2, N))
b = np.random.uniform(-1., 1., N)

c = []
for i in range(M1):
    for j in range(M2):
        c.append(np.cov(a[i][j], b)[0, 1])

c1 = np.reshape(c, (M1, M2))

ac = a - a.mean(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
bc = (b - b.mean()) / (N-1)

c2 = np.dot(ac, bc)
c3 = np.einsum('ijk,k->ij', ac, bc)
print(np.allclose(c1, c2))
print(np.allclose(c1, c3))
```

Prints

```
True
True
```

Comment: Good to see you back! Was tinkering around with these for a while, couldn't get through though. `tensordot` would be better than `dot` on tensors : `np.tensordot(ac, bc, axes=((-1,-1)))`.

Comment: All three options (`np.einsum`, `np.dot`, `np.tensordot`) are a lot faster than the `for` block. Since apparently they are all equally fast, I'll go with `np.dot` which is (to me) the simpler to interpret. Thank you both!